# Webservice not call from right fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

My question is when i call webservice from 3rd or any of fragment reside into viewpager that not call when i open this fragment but instend of that ii got result when viewpager start. In short the webservice call before open that fragment in which have webservice code.

Comment: Put some code then I'll help you.

Comment: Thnx for reply but i could not paste entire code here because project is large so if you have take example than please suggest me the solution

Comment: Sorry i can't under your question please put more information or try to explain with some picture.

Answer (score 0):

As per your restriction of not putting your code here , i can help you as per of my assumptions.
what i think is happening here:  when you load your View pager, it itself loaded 1st 2 items.like if you at page 2(in respect of view pager) it also load 1st and page 3rd.
so your functions and code written in 3rd fragment automatically called before opening that particular fragment.

Solution : just keep a check for that particular code that it get called when actually fragment open not otherwise.

Comment: ohk brother i will try ...thnx a lot